# What is ethash shared mode?

Tags: go-ethereum, mining-pools, ethash

I red over ethash source code and saw this code:

`func CreatePoW(config *Config) (pow.PoW, error) {
    switch {
    case config.PowFake:
        glog.V(logger.Info).Infof("ethash used in fake mode")
        return pow.PoW(core.FakePow{}), nil
    case config.PowTest:
        glog.V(logger.Info).Infof("ethash used in test mode")
        return ethash.NewForTesting()
    case config.PowShared:
        glog.V(logger.Info).Infof("ethash used in shared mode")
        return ethash.NewShared(), nil
    default:
        return ethash.New(), nil
    }
}`

What does **shared mode** mean? And when is ethash in shared mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the answer from [Péter Szilágyi](https://github.com/karalabe) on go-ethereum gitter channel so I paste here for people who come by.

> If I remember correctly, the "shared PoW" is only used inside our
>   tests. The idea was that generating a PoW DAG, even a small one for
>   testing takes time. Since we have hundreds of thousands of random
>   tests, even small times add up to giant test runtimes, which is
>   completely wasteful given that they use the same DAG anyway. The idea
>   behind the shared PoW was that there's a global DAG instance that is
>   shared between all instances, so when you do an ethash.NewShared it
>   will only generate a new one if non exists currently, otherwise it
>   will return that. Originally all test dags worked like this afaik, and
>   we needed to make it explicit when introducing some tests that
>   actually need multiple generations of dags.